# g1 gc write barrier: exclusive-or and shifts

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, jvm-hotspot, g1gc

I am reading the paper Garbage-First Garbage Collection ([http://cs.williams.edu/~dbarowy/cs334s18/assets/p37-detlefs.pdf](http://cs.williams.edu/%7Edbarowy/cs334s18/assets/p37-detlefs.pdf)), in section 2.2 it mentions the write barrier. In order to filter out the object from the same region, it has the following code, when `rTmp` is 0 means `rX` and `rY` contains pointer from the same region

```
rTmp := rX XOR rY
rTmp := rTmp >> LogOfHeapRegionSize
```

But if assume LogOfHeapRegionSize is 4 (bin=100), and rX starts the address (bin 0), rY starts the address (bin 111), clearly, they are not in the same region, but apply the code above, we have

```
111 XOR 000 = 111
111 >> 4 = 0
```

gives they are in the same region, why? Am I understand the code in the right way?

Comment: LogOfHeapRegionSize=4 would mean the region size is 2⁴=16. Addresses 000b (0) and 111b (7) are both in the range 0-15, thus both belong to the first region.